# Concurrent Execution: Future vs parallelstream

Tags: java, performance, parallel-processing, java-stream, future

I wrote a callable that polls a remote client for information and returns that information in List form. I'm using a threadpoolexecutor, for loop, and Future to execute the task in parallel against multiple remote clients. Then I combine all of the Future lists with addAll() and work with the giant combined list.

My question is, would using parallelstream() be more efficient here than using future and a for loop? It's certainly easier to code! If I went that route would I need the threadpoolexecutor anymore?

Thank you!

```
        for(SiteInfo site : active_sites) {
            TAG_SCANNER scanr = new TAG_SCANNER(site, loggr);
            Future<List<TagInfo>> result = threadmaker.submit(scanr);

            //SOUND THE ALARMS
            try {
                alarm_tags.addAll(result.get());
            } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

Possible solution code? Netbeans is suggesting something along these lines

```
active_sites.parallelstream().map((site) -> new TAG_SCANNER(site, loggr)).map((scanr) -> threadmaker.submit(scanr)).forEach((result) -> {
            //SOUND THE ALARMS
            try {
                alarm_tags.addAll(result.get());
            }
            catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
```

Comment: @sinu code posted.

Comment: With that implementation, it sure would be faster, because your current implementation is sequential: after submitting a task, instead of submitting others and waiting for all tasks to finish, you wait for the current task to complete before submitting the next one. So you would be faster by doing everything in a single thread.

Comment: I think I get that now. I thought future would make things function in parallel but I suppose the for loop is what's keeping things sequential? parallelstream it is! Unless rewriting what I have so that it runs in parallel will produce better results?

Comment: No. You calling get() immediately after submitting the task is what makes it sequential. There is far fewer chances of introducing such a bug with a parallel stream, but you won't have your word on how many concurrent threads are allowed to execute your tasks.

Comment: @JBNizet I think I understand. Calling get on that future object means that I'm essentially telling the computer, hey wait for this call's output before running this get(), which in turn keeps the end of the for loop from being reached and prevents parallel processing.

Would the second code block i posted run in parallel?

Comment: ParallelStream already parallelize its opeations. You don't need to submit tasks to an executor when using a parallel stream. Just program it as you would do for a sequential stream.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are several misconceptions here. First, using an asynchronous task does not improve your resource utilization, if you call `Future.get` right after submitting the task, immediately waiting for its completion before submitting the next task.

Second, the code transformation made by Netbeans produced a mostly equivalent code, still submitting tasks to an `Executor` so it’s not a matter of “Future vs parallelstream” as you are only performing the submission (and waiting) with the  parallel stream and still using the executor. Due to your first error, doing it in parallel might improve the throughput, but besides that it is never a good idea to combine two mistakes to let them cancel themselves out, it’s still a poor solution:

The standard implementation of the Stream API is optimized for CPU-bound tasks, creating a number of threads matching the number of CPU cores and not spawning new threads when these threads get blocked in a wait operation. So using parallel streams for performing I/O operations, or generally operations which may wait, is not a good choice. And you have no control over the threads used by the implementation.

The better choice is staying with the `ExecutorService` which you can configure according to your expected I/O bandwidth to your remote clients. But you should fix the error of waiting immediately after submission, submitting all tasks first and waiting for the completion of all tasks afterwards. Note that you can use the stream API for that, not for better parallelism, but potentially improving the readability:

```
// first, submit all tasks, assuming "threadmaker" is an ExecutorService
List<Future<List<TagInfo>>> futures=threadmaker.invokeAll(
    active_sites.stream()
        .map(site -> new TAG_SCANNER(site, loggr))
        .collect(Collectors.toList())
);
// now fetch all results
for(Future<List<TagInfo>> result: futures) {
    //SOUND THE ALARMS
    try {
        alarm_tags.addAll(result.get());
    } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
        // not a recommended way of handling
        // but I keep your code here for simplicity
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Note that the stream API use here is *sequential* and only for converting your list of `SiteInfo` to a list of `Callable<List<TagInfo>>`, but you could do the same using a loop.

Comment: Thank you! I think my understanding of how Future works and how the stream API works are both a little better now! Your answer clarifies some things that I'd been having a little difficulty with.

Answer (score 5):

In general `parallelstream` has been written by very smart programmers to do parallel processing very effectively.

With that, as with all the other java threading such as the concurrency package then unless you are an expert in the subject then if you write it yourself you are likely to:

- Run slower
- Introduce bugs
- Have more complex/harder to follow/etc code

In other words: **Yes, use parallelstream**.

Comment: Cool! That makes things a little more readable and NetBeans almost did all of the work converting it for me. Thanks!

Comment: @TheFunk: don’t be so hasty. Did you really understand [JB Nizet’s comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36456032/concurrent-execution-future-vs-parallelstream/36458106#comment60526258_36456032)?

Comment: @Holger I think so, yeah.

The call to get() is keeping my for loop from iterating because I'm waiting to get the results before restarting my loop? I would assume parallelstream wouldn't have this issue because everything after parallelstream can run concurrently. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: @TheFunk: if you’re going to use the stream API for parallel processing, you should do it consistently, removing the use of the Executor altogether, as only then you can assume that it will prevent the bugs you can make with an Executor. But for this specific task, using I/O, the stream API is not the best choice.